# CSS Grid: How do I make an item span the entire column?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have a grid layout.
Now I want the `.left` element to span across the entire column like this:

[image]

But I tried to make it `grid-row: auto / -1;` and it does not seem to work.

I can't change the html structure nor hard code it to `grid-row: auto / span xx` since the number of the elements is not certain.

How do I make the first element always span the entire column?

```css
section {
  counter-reset: spans;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 80px repeat(auto-fill, minmax(160px, 1fr));
  gap: 4px;
}

section span {
  counter-increment: spans;
  border: solid 1px #aaa;
}

section span::before {
  content: counter(spans);
}

.left {
  grid-row: auto / -1;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <span class="left"></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to define the columns and rows.

```
    section {
  counter-reset: spans;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 1fr);
  gap: 4px;
}

section span {
  counter-increment: spans;
  border: solid 1px #aaa;
}

section span::before {
  content: counter(spans);
}

.left {
  grid-row: 1 / -1;
}
```

If you face any problems let me know.

Comment: But the items are not certain. There might be 100 items and only 3 items. How can I make this layout universal?

Comment: You could have gone with auto-fill & and minmax to do that. But theres no way for you to span the 1st element the entire row. This is just not possible. You must have a defined rows to do that.